# Visual Studio SDK - GetClassificationSpans doesn't get called

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

In my classifier class I have a method containing the code below:

```
var handler = ClassificationChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
        IVsTextManager textManager = (IVsTextManager)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
        IVsTextView vTextView = null;
        int mustHaveFocus = 1;
        textManager.GetActiveView(mustHaveFocus, null, out vTextView);
        IVsUserData userData = vTextView as IVsUserData;
        if (userData != null)
        {
            IWpfTextViewHost viewHost;
            object holder;
            Guid guidViewHost = DefGuidList.guidIWpfTextViewHost;
            userData.GetData(ref guidViewHost, out holder);
            viewHost = (IWpfTextViewHost)holder;
            IWpfTextView textView = viewHost.TextView;
            ITextSnapshot textSnapshot = textView.TextSnapshot;
            SnapshotSpan span = new SnapshotSpan(textSnapshot, 0, textSnapshot.Length);

            var eventArgs = new ClassificationChangedEventArgs(span);
            handler(this, eventArgs);
        }
}
```

When I call my method, [GetClassificationSpans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.classification.iclassifier.getclassificationspans.aspx) doesn't get called. I don't understand why. Is there anything I do wrong? How can I force Visual Studio to call GetClassificationSpans and reapply classification formats to the code when no edit occurred?

Comment: `GetClassificationSpans` of what instance?  Are you sure it applies to that TextBuffer / ContentType?

Comment: @SLaks I made a mistake in the first sentence. This method shown above is a part of my **classifier** class (implementing IClassifier interface) and the GetClassificationSpans method is in the same class

Comment: Are you sure you have the right buffer?

Comment: Thank you @SLaks. Your suggestion led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the TextBuffer as SLaks suggested and it led me to the solution. I have a reference to my classifier somewhere else in the code to call my method mentioned in the question. However, it turned out to be a reference to another classifier which had different TextBuffer. I made sure the reference was right and now everything works correctly.